# quickly dynamically load assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, portability

I am trying to make my application completely portable (all dependencies embedded within the executable), except for the fact that it's quite slow. It takes about ~1.2 seconds to fully load the application, and I've discovered that loading the assemblies from the resources (The binary is embedded as "embedded resource") is quite slow. (400ms). Is there anyway to quickly dynamically load my dependencies? (Also, it would be great if somebody could tell me how to speed up InitializeComponent)
Here is my code:

```
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
            {
                string resource = nameof(Ink_Pad) + "." + new AssemblyName(e.Name).Name + ".dll";
                using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                    return Assembly.Load(data);
                }
            };
```

Thanks

Comment: This is probably really stupid of me, but trying Assembly.Load and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load doesn't actually load the assemblies. It just returns a assembly; what am i supposed to do with it?

Comment: @VisualUser, sorry about that bad advice on preloading (now deleted).  I forgot that loading the assembly does not automatically  make it resolve to that loaded assembly.

Comment: @TnTinMn Ok, thanks for trying to help me.